# mpack command in ksh script, ftp file first from windows

Tags: unix, ftp, ksh, aix

```
WORK_FILE=RetriesExceeded.csv
MAIL="test@test.org"
HOST=lawsonfax

$FTP -v "$HOST" << EOF

get RetriesExceeded.csv
quit 
EOF

archive_file $WORK_FILE

/law/bin/mpack -s 'Fax Retries Exceeded' "$WORK_FILE" "$MAIL"

log_stop
exit 0
```

Newest error at bottom, no such file or directory:     [dgftp@lawapp2]/lawif/bin$ get_lawson_fax.ksh

Connected to lawsonfax.phsi.promedica.org.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
331 Password required for dgftp.
230 User logged in.
200 PORT command successful.
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
226 Transfer complete.
352 bytes received in 0.04171 seconds (8.242 Kbytes/s)
local: RetriesExceeded.csv remote: RetriesExceeded.csv
221 Goodbye.
RetriesExceeded.csv: No such file or directory
[dgftp@lawapp2]/lawif/bin$

Comment: `mpack` is never executed in this script; the last is just a variable-assignment, not a program-execution.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this command and quite frankly ksh scripting.  What do you mean and what do you recommend?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The last command now:

```
CMD="/law/bin/mpack -s 'Fax Retries Exceeded' $WORK_FILE $MAIL"
```

Suggested change:

```
/law/bin/mpack -s 'Fax Retries Exceeded' "$WORK_FILE" "$MAIL"
```

Of course only if you actually have such `/law/bin/mpack` program.

Comment: Connected to lawsonfax
220 Microsoft FTP Service
331 Password required for dgftp.
230 User logged in.
200 PORT command successful.
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
226 Transfer complete.
352 bytes received in 0.08696 seconds (3.953 Kbytes/s)
local: RetriesExceeded.csv remote: RetriesExceeded.csv
221 Goodbye.
RetriesExceeded.csv: No such file or directory
[dgftp@lawapp2]/lawif/bin$

Comment: no such file or directory.  script is seeing that line now.

Comment: Yeah, we have mpack.

Comment: I have another script that uses this:  CMD="/law/bin/mpack -s 'NCB recon cb185_${SITE}man.txt' $WORK_DIR/cb185_${SITE}man.txt $MAIL_TO"

Comment: If you've changed your script, then please edit your original post, append the new code and the error message.

Comment: You seem to have `/lawif` not `/law`.